# How to add a Font to a pdf using PDFGen in C

Tags: c, pdf, fonts

**Context:**
I'm working on a program that will generate PDF files from a set of images.
I'm using this library: https://github.com/AndreRenaud/PDFGen.

**Problem:**
I want to use Calibri-Bold as the font of each PDF cover page, everything works fine except when I open the output.pdf file there is an error "The font 'Calibri-Bold' contains a bad /BBox" and the letters aren't spaced correctly.

**Code:**

```
#include "pdfgen.h"

int main(void) {
    struct pdf_info info = {
            .creator = "",
            .producer = "Band'a la Page",
            .title = "Piccolo book",
            .author = "Theo SARDA",
            .subject = "Band'Ales book for Piccolo",
            .date = "Today"
    };
    struct pdf_doc *pdf = pdf_create(PDF_A6_HEIGHT, PDF_A6_WIDTH, &info);
    pdf_set_font(pdf, "Calibri-Bold");
    pdf_append_page(pdf);
    float x[] = {PDF_MM_TO_POINT(0), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(80), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(100), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(60), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(0)};
    float y[] = {PDF_MM_TO_POINT(0), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(0), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(70), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(105), PDF_MM_TO_POINT(105)};

    pdf_add_filled_polygon(pdf, NULL, x, y, 5, 0, PDF_ARGB(0xFF, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00));
    pdf_add_text(pdf, NULL, "Carnet Piccolo", 12, 30, 30, PDF_WHITE);
    //pdf_add_line(pdf, NULL, 50, 24, 150, 24, 3, PDF_BLACK);
    pdf_save(pdf, "output.pdf");
    pdf_destroy(pdf);
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**
Screenshot:

[image]

**Question:**
How can I use the Calibri-Bold font without getting this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you try using this font with another software, for example Word, to check if this font is installed correctly on your PC?

Comment: Of course yes, and even tried opening the exported files with notepad++ to see the differences, but I didn't really understood what was in it.

Comment: I must precise that the font displayed is the right one... But I get an error and a bad character spacing.